# How to change the order in which the data appears in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot that shows the mean and standard deviation of my data. I have the code that creates the plot, and it works. However, my points are out of order. Below is the data that is being plotted (called Sumcircle):

```
    reduction.area.size  antlerless.harvest.rate.sink  mean      sd
    1                    0.3                           23.14362  5.1980318
    5                    0.3                           24.82013  2.9770937
    10                   0.3                           25.30464  1.9167845
    15                   0.3                           25.27654  1.6662350
    20                   0.3                           24.86209  1.5823747
    25                   0.3                           25.17401  1.3082544
    1                    0.35                          20.65101  4.9711989
    5                    0.35                          21.47942  2.6411690
    10                   0.35                          21.72935  1.8211059
    15                   0.35                          21.30290  1.6275956
    20                   0.35                          21.49806  1.3869719
    25                   0.35                          21.10958  1.1720223
    1                    0.4                           18.09449  4.8401543
    5                    0.4                           17.56596  2.2518005
    10                   0.4                           18.22319  1.7100441
    15                   0.4                           17.89776  1.2087007
    20                   0.4                           17.84899  1.2016877
    25                   0.4                           18.05289  1.0047864
    1                    0.45                          14.35913  4.0633069
    5                    0.45                          14.78276  2.1630511
    10                   0.45                          15.18299  1.6615803
    15                   0.45                          14.83019  1.2601986
    20                   0.45                          14.90748  1.1107997
    25                   0.45                          14.69429  0.8485477
    1                    0.5                           11.75290  3.5159347
    5                    0.5                           12.10627  2.2036029
    10                   0.5                           12.47646  1.4440110
    15                   0.5                           12.31346  0.9431687
    20                   0.5                           12.20568  0.9091177
    25                   0.5                           12.14800  0.8264364
```

Here is the code I use to create the plot:

```
    library(ggplot2)

    pd = position_dodge(.8)    

   circlelineplot<-ggplot(Sumcircle,                

              aes(x     = antlerless.harvest.rate.sink,
                  y     = mean,
                  color = reduction.area.size)) +

     geom_point(shape = 15, 
         size  = 4, 
         position = pd) +

    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin  = mean - sd,
                ymax  = mean + sd),
            width = 0.2, 
            size  = 0.7, 
            position = pd) +
     theme_bw() +
     theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "bold")) 

    # Change the y axis name
    circlelineplot +  ggtitle("Population Density in Circular Reduction 
    Area with 30 deer/mi2 Ambient Density")  +

     theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) +

     scale_y_continuous(name ="End Population Density"), 
                 breaks=seq(0,30,5)) + 

     scale_x_discrete(name ="Antlerless Harvest Rate",
               breaks=c("0.3","0.35","0.4","0.45","0.5"),
               labels=c("30%","35%","40%","45%","50%")) + 

     scale_color_manual(values=c("brown","brown1","brown2","brown3",
     "brown4","darkred"), name="Size of Reduction Area",
    limits=c("1","5","10","15","20","25"))
```

However, this code gives me the following plot:

[image]

How do I get the data for the size "5" reduction area to go between the data for sizes "1" and "10"? I thought the limits function would do that, but it is not. Thanks for any help!

Comment: With exact posted data and code: `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`

Comment: as an attempt to translate @Parfait's comment - without having even tried to reproduce the long code, there is likely a problem of having your data stored as discrete variable - thus, R reads 5 as more than 25, and it will be plotted as last variable. To change that, convert to factors and define the order of your levels.

Comment: Thank you! My variables were already converted to factors, but I defined my levels to be "unique(reduction.area.size)" and that fixed the issue.